# HTML jQuery Table Filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have been working on my jQuery filtering for a HTML table. The filters work individually but I can't get them to work for each other.

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/b8Lu55pL/1/

For example if you set the Client Payment Filtering to "Client 2nd Payment Paid" ***after*** setting the Application Status Filtering to "Deadend" it will still show 1 row even though it should be showing none.

How can I fix this? I looked at DataTables but chose against it so that it is more custom etc.

Thanks.

For reference, the JS is:

```
var clientfirst = $('th:contains("Client First Payment")').index();
var clientsecond = $('th:contains("Client Second Payment")').index();
var clientthird = $('th:contains("Client Third Payment")').index();

var franchisefirst = $('th:contains("Franchise First Payment")').index();
var franchisesecond = $('th:contains("Franchise Second Payment")').index();
var franchisethird = $('th:contains("Franchise Third Payment")').index();

var application_index = $('th:contains("Application Status")').index();


jQuery( "#clientfees" ).change(function() {
    var clientfeesfilter = jQuery(this).val();
    var index = null;
    if(clientfeesfilter == "1st"){
         index = clientfirst;
    }else if(clientfeesfilter == "2nd"){
        index = clientsecond;
    }else if(clientfeesfilter == "3rd") {
        index = clientthird;
    }else if(clientfeesfilter == "none"){
        show_non_paid("Client");
    }else{
        jQuery('#table > tbody > tr').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).show();
        });
    }
    if(index != null){
        search_fees_by_index(index);
    }
});


jQuery( "#franchisefees" ).change(function() {
    var franchisefeesfilter = jQuery(this).val();
    var index = null;
    if(franchisefeesfilter == "1st"){
        index = franchisefirst;
    }else if(franchisefeesfilter == "2nd"){
        index = franchisesecond;
    }else if(franchisefeesfilter == "3rd") {
        index = franchisethird;
    }else if(franchisefeesfilter == "none"){
        show_non_paid("Franchise");
    }else{
        jQuery('#table > tbody > tr').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).show();
        });
    }
    if(index != null){
        search_fees_by_index(index);
    }
});

function search_fees_by_index(index){
    jQuery('#table > tbody > tr').each(function(){
        var cell = getCell(index, jQuery(this).index(), "table");
        if(cell.innerHTML == ""){
            jQuery(this).hide();
        }else{
            jQuery(this).show();
        }
    });
}
function show_non_paid(type){
    jQuery('#table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
        if (type == "Client") {
            var first = getCell(clientfirst, jQuery(this).index(), "table").innerHTML;
            var second = getCell(clientsecond, jQuery(this).index(), "table").innerHTML;
            var third = getCell(clientthird, jQuery(this).index(), "table").innerHTML;
        }
        if (type == "Franchise") {
            var first = getCell(franchisefirst, jQuery(this).index(), "table").innerHTML;
            var second = getCell(franchisesecond, jQuery(this).index(), "table").innerHTML;
            var third = getCell(franchisethird, jQuery(this).index(), "table").innerHTML;
        }
        if(first == "" && second == "" && third == ""){
            jQuery(this).show();
        }else{
            jQuery(this).hide();
        }
    });
}

function getCell(column, row, tableId) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    return table.rows[row+1].cells[column];
}

jQuery( "#application_status_filter" ).change(function() {
    var status_filter = jQuery(this).val();

    if(status_filter == ""){
        jQuery('#table > tbody > tr').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).show();
        });
    }else {
        jQuery('#table > tbody > tr').each(function () {
            var cell = getCell(application_index, jQuery(this).index(), "table");
            if (cell.innerHTML == status_filter) {
                jQuery(this).show();
            } else {
                jQuery(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And the HTML is:

```
<select id="clientfees">
   <option value="">Client Payment Filtering</option>
   <option value="none">Client No Payments Paid</option>
   <option value="1st">Client 1st Payment Paid</option>
   <option value="2nd">Client 2nd Payment Paid</option>
   <option value="3rd">Client 3rd Payment Paid</option>
</select>
<select id="franchisefees">
   <option value="">Franchise Payment Filtering</option>
   <option value="none">Franchise No Payments Paid</option>
   <option value="1st">Franchise 1st Payment Paid</option>
   <option value="2nd">Franchise 2nd Payment Paid</option>
   <option value="3rd">Franchise 3rd Payment Paid</option>
</select>
<select id="application_status_filter">
   <option value="">Application Status Filtering</option>
   <option value="Prospective Student">Prospective Student</option>
   <option value="Deadend">Deadend</option>
   <option value="Awaiting First Installment Fee">Awaiting First Installment Fee</option>
   <option value="Submitted to University">Submitted to University</option>
   <option value="Awaiting Second Installment Fee">Awaiting Second Installment Fee</option>
   <option value="Accepted by University">Accepted by University</option>
   <option value="Awaiting Third Installment Fee">Awaiting Third Installment Fee</option>
   <option value="Rejected by University">Rejected by University</option>
   <option value="Discussing Further Options">Discussing Further Options</option>
</select>
<br /><br />

<div class="table-responsive">
   <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Name As Per Passport</th>
            <th>Franchise ID</th>
            <th>Nationality</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Telephone Number</th>
            <th>Mobile Number</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Fathers Name</th>
            <th>Fathers Contact Number</th>
            <th>Mothers Name</th>
            <th>Mothers Contact Number</th>
            <th>Course Applied For</th>
            <th>University Choice</th>
            <th>Date Application Submitted</th>
            <th>Application Status</th>
            <th>Last Contacted</th>
            <th>Client First Payment Details</th>
            <th>Client Second Payment Details</th>
            <th>Client Third Payment Details</th>
            <th>Franchise First Payment Details</th>
            <th>Franchise Second Payment Details</th>
            <th>Franchise Third Payment Details</th>
         </tr>
      <tbody>
         <tr onclick='redirect_no_confirm("/client.php?id=1");' style="cursor:pointer;">
            <td>Shivam Paw</td>
            <td>KOL</td>
            <td>United Kingdom</td>
            <td>2000-09-12</td>
            <td>XXXXX<br />
              vgubh<br />
               yugh<br />
               United Kingdom
            </td>
            <td>12345678</td>
            <td>12345678</td>
            <td>2345@345ty.com</td>
            <td>Pranay</td>
            <td>23456y7ui</td>
            <td>Kajal</td>
            <td>3456789</td>
            <td>Medicine</td>
            <td>Varna</td>
            <td>2016-08-07</td>
            <td>Rejected by University</td>
            <td>2016-08-09</td>
            <td>Paid &pound;1000 on 10th August 2016</td>
            <td>Paid &pound;800 on 11th August 2016</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Paid &pound;800 on 10th August 2016</td>
            <td>Paid &pound;700 on 11th August 2016</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr onclick='redirect_no_confirm("/client.php?id=2");' style="cursor:pointer;">
            <td>James</td>
            <td>NAG</td>
            <td>United Kingdom</td>
            <td>1978-03-13</td>
            <td>24 Scott Road<br />
               Walsall<br />
               WS5 3JN
            </td>
            <td>018378271082</td>
            <td>1672832497</td>
            <td>test@shivampaw.com</td>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>215673487</td>
            <td>Carol</td>
            <td>36284759884976</td>
            <td>Dentistry</td>
            <td>Varna</td>
            <td>2016-08-10</td>
            <td>Prospective Student</td>
            <td>2016-08-07</td>
            <td>Paid £100 today.</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Any ideas about this?

Comment: Still need help with this.